# ANTLR4: How to override text in lexer subrule/fragment

Tags: antlr, antlr4

The syntax I'm trying to parse includes a continuation indicator in column 71.
Identifiers, literals, almost anything can be continued onto the next line.

Ideally, I would like to drop the characters which make up the continue token,
so that I'm left with only the identifier characters.
However, using the following lexer rules, the 'setText("")' in LINE_CONTINUATION
is ignored, thus polluting the final IDENTIFIER token.

```
IDENTIFIER 
    : 
    {getCharPositionInLine() < 71 }? IDENTIFIER_PART
    (
            {getCharPositionInLine() < 71 }? IDENTIFIER_PART  
        |   LINE_CONTINUATION 
    )*
;
fragment IDENTIFIER_PART: (LETTER|DIGIT|'_');
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
fragment LETTER options { caseInsensitive=true; } : [A-Z];

//A continuation line is non-blank in column 72, followed by anything until EOL,
//then on next line the characters starting after column position 15
LINE_CONTINUATION
    : 
    {getCharPositionInLine() == 71 }? 
    ~[ ] 
    ~[\r\n]* EOL
    ({getCharPositionInLine() <= 15 }? [ ] )+  
    {setText("");}
;
```

Is there anyway of overriding the value of a subrule (or fragment) in the same way
that root rules can be overridden?

For example, there could be a list of identifiers defined as:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAA,BBBBBBBBBBB,CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC,DDDDDDDDDDD,EEEEEEEEEE,FFFF* Some comment
FFFF,GGGGGGGG
```

I'm trying to get tokens with text:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDD
EEEEEEEEEE
FFFFFFFF
GGGGGGGG
```

However I get:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDDDDD
EEEEEEEEEE
FFFF* Some comment\nFFFF
GGGGGGGG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible. You will have to do the `setText(…)` inside your `IDENTIFIER` rule. Try something like this (untested):

```
IDENTIFIER
 : {getCharPositionInLine() < 71 }? IDENTIFIER_PART
   ( {getCharPositionInLine() < 71 }? IDENTIFIER_PART  
   | LINE_CONTINUATION 
   )*
   {
     String text = getText();
     setText(text.replaceAll(“\\S[^\r\n]*[\r\n]+[ ]{0,15}”, “”));
   }
;
```

Comment: Thanks Bart, that is a good suggestion, however the regex to find the start of the continuation part is quite difficult. The problem is there can be characters after the continuation and before the EOL. Ideally, to find the continuation pos (column 71), I need the start column pos of the token, plus length of the token, however I can only see getCharPositionInLine() - that gives the end column of the token, and because it is on the second line it will be useless. Is there anyway to get the start position of the token at this point?

Comment: With fragments, there is no position that you can use from inside the IDENTIFIER rule. But I don’t see how my suggested regex is very different than what you do in your fragmet. Note that \S matches a non-space char, similar to your `~[ ]` (you could also do `[^ ]` instead of \S)

Comment: Could you indicate what input is not correctly handled by the regex?

Comment: Sorry for not giving the full story, I tried to simplify the question for brevity! The regex wasn't quite right for me because string literals could also be continued, so there may be spaces before the continuation character (which is actually any non-blank character, but must be in position 71). I've found _tokenStartCharPositionInLine which does the trick for me. I can use that to get all the characters up to column 71, then after the EOL I trim off up to 15 blanks before the first non-blank. Thanks for your help Bart!